# Swift 4, pass async data to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a problem to pass data from a Firebase async function.

The action to pass is a through a collection cell. When I tap a cell this should obtain the data from firebase, once obtain the data it should pass it to other viewcontroller.

My problem is that the view controller shows before the data is obtained.

It is my code in my prepare segue method:

```
AlbumModel.getAlbumByID(id: "album1") {
        result in
        albumDetailViewController.album = result

}
```

`AlbumModel.getAlbumByID` is a completion handler function.

Any suggestion how to make this sync?

Answer (score 0):

*Don't make it sync!*

Two suggestions:

- Use `didSelectRow` to catch the tap, get the data and call `performSegue` on completion.
- Pass `album1` in the segue as parameter and get the data in the destination controller.

In both cases put the code to process the returned `album` in the completion handler.

Comment: Dear downvoter: Making an asynchronous task synchronous is very bad habit and is no solution in this case.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried second suggestion, but I have a delay to get data, initially view controller shows default info for album (for example NAME_LABEL). it change once the data is get.

Comment: Of course there is a delay. Even if you made the task synchronous there is a delay. Maybe suggestion one is more suitable. You could show an progress indicator.

Comment: Regardless of whether you load the data first or second, it is important to provide user feedback during the load (such as an activity view) so that the user can see something is happening and that you load appropriate placeholder data (maybe empty strings) if you are doing it second.